# Django and South: No default specified for null=True

Tags: django, database-migration, django-south

I have a Foreign Field and I am trying to set it as unrequired.

So here it is:

```
team = models.ForeignKey('acpkinballmanageteams.Team',blank=True,null=True,related_name="grey_team",verbose_name=_("grey team"),on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

But for some reason, when I try to run schemamigration --auto on the model, I keep getting no default specified yet is not null.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Ara

Comment: just add 'default=None' in `models.ForeignKey()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

South is asking you for a default value in case you make a rollback(in this case make the field `team` mandatory again).

So you can enter a default value (to be used by the null fields in case of a reverse migration) or you disable the backwards migration.